# Receive "TypeError: string indices must be integers" when iterating over one piece of code

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am taking an input with

```
CC = (input("What is your credit card number?"))
```

When I take the sum of every other digit, starting from the first, I use this code (which works):

```
amex_sum = sum(int(i) for i in CC[::2])
```

However, when I try to take the sum of every other digit, starting from the second digit and until the 16th digit, with the following code

```
MC_sum = sum(int(i) for i in CC[1,15,2])
```

I receive the error: "TypeError: string indices must be integers."

Why does one iteration work and not the other? Isn't the code essentially the same?

Comment: `1,15,2` creates a **tuple** of numbers, hence the error.

Comment: Yes, surely you mean `1::2`

Comment: You need to use `:` instead of `,`, like `1:15:2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're slicing it incorrectly, you are doing`CC[1,15,2]` but this creates a tuple `(1, 15, 2)` to be indexed in `CC` This wont work of course as CC is a string and takes only integer indices.

What you want is `CC[1:15:2]` to slice from the second index to the sixteenth with a step of two.